# Python error "AttributeError module 'string' has no attribute 'lstrip' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

When starting this code, I can’t save the file found on the website. I get an error  "AttributeError module 'string' has no attribute 'lstrip' "
I can not solve the problem with " string.lstpri" , help find my mistake?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize
import time
import urllib.request
import string


start = "http://www.irrelevantcheetah.com/browserimages.html"# test website 
filetype = input("What file type are you looking for?\n")

br = mechanize.Browser()
r = br.open(start)
html = r.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    linkText = str(link)
    fileName = str(link.get('href'))
    if filetype in fileName:
       image = urllib.request.URLopener()
       linkGet = "http://www.irrelevantcheetah.com" + fileName
       filesave = string.lstrip(fileName, '/')
       image.retrieve(linkGet, filesave)
```

Comment: `filesave = string.lstrip(fileName, '/')` should be `filesave = fileName.lstrip('/')`  `string` is name of module you`ve imported before

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
I tried this method before, apparently somewhere I made a mistake and it did not work. Now everything worked out

Answer (score -1):

[Andrej Kesely gave the solution in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204850/pyton-erro-attributeerror-module-string-has-no-attribute-lstrip#comment104627681_59204850):

> `filesave = string.lstrip(fileName, '/')` should be `filesave = fileName.lstrip('/')`  `string` is name of module you`ve imported before